# Format Phone Number SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure that in part, pulls phone numbers from a database.
In some cases, the number may be in an incorrect format. The correct format is:
+714XXXXXXX, however there are cases where the number appears as, e.g: 142877261
or 7147267261. There are even some cases where the number appears as say, ++1749186372

How can i force the number to append +714 to the start while keeping the rest of the  number intact?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First order of business is making sure they're normalized going in from now on.

Comment: If you would share some of your own attempts one of the community would be glad to help you along with your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the 7 most right digits and unconditionnaly preprending +714

```
'+714' + right(phonenumber, 7)
```